# How to make https links available to anonymous when new article is published?

Tags: 7, navigation

When content/article is created the content is accessible first on the http link and then later the httpS link. There is usually a delay of at least 5mns for anonymous  to access it.

http://example.com/item-just-published
vs
https://example.com/item-just-published

The cache settings have been modified for the content type to refresh cache on update and insert but it seems to affect the http links only not httpS. This is a problem as some time sensitive items don't get to the audience in a timely matter using httpS links.

example.com/admin/config/development/performance

[image]

example.com/admin/config/system/expire
[image]

How to make httpS links available as soon as it is published to anonymous?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both secure and non-secure websites are in fact the same Drupal instance, there are a few possibilities which may cause the issue you are experiencing:

1. **Web server; configuration differences in secure non-secure sites.**
   Compare both website settings. Only difference should be SSL specific settings, rest should be same or inheriting settings from other's. if necessary, refer to web server's official documentation.
2. **Web server; misconfiguration in redirect rules**
   From your comments it's clear that both websites are actually available. Still there could be redirect rules needs correcting.
3. **HTTP or HTTPS version of the site has an external caching system**
   Check if there is caching system or proxy enabled for either of the sites. i.e. Varnish, Redis, CloudFlare.

Please provide some more details about the webserver (Apache, nginx, IIS, etc), and currently installed caching and performance related modules.

Also, you can consider serving the site only on HTTPS, to avoid penalties from search engines for duplicate content.

Comment: +1 for serving on HTTPS only. There is no merit in serving on both protocols nowadays.